# How to get menu item id on action bar when other menu item clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-2.3-gingerbread

So I have menu items on action bar. on onOptionsItemSelected, I want to change the menu items images.

Here's my code

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.todaySched:{
        viewTodaySched();
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.calendarselected);
        infoLog=(MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.infoLog);
        infoLog.setIcon(R.drawable.book);

        return true;}
    case R.id.infoLog:{
        viewInfoLog();
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.bookselected);
                    todaySched=(MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.todaySched);
        todaySched.setIcon(R.drawable.calenderselected);
        return true;}
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But the icon won't change when I clicked it, and I got run time error.
e.g: When I click todaySched icon, It seems like I can't get the infoLog item id.

My LogCat: [LogCat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wfz0ogkh57vbtz/log.txt)

Comment: Why are you having brackets `{}` around switch statements like `R.id.todaySched:{` ?

Comment: @mohit I just provided my LogCat on my question.

Comment: what is line 211 on MainActivity?

Comment: @mohit infoLog=(MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.infoLog);

Comment: log link missing

Answer (score 7):

As per you logcat, you getting ***class cast exception*** and you have used **sharlockactionbar**.
so try and check if you have imported the correct MenuItem and Menu which should like this:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
and
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
```

instead of

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
and
import android.view.Menu;
```

**Edit:**

Here is how you can change both icons on just a single click:

```
  private Menu menu;
private MenuItem item1, item2;
Boolean original = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    this.menu = menu;
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.todaySched) {
        update();

    } else if (id == R.id.infoLog) {

        update();
    }

    return true;

}

private void update() {

    item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.todaySched);
    item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.infoLog);

    if (original) {
        item1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        item2.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image));
        original = false;
    } else if (!original) {

        item1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_my_calendar));
        item2.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details));
        original = true;
    }

}
```

checked and is working. Now use it as per your requirement..

Cheers....

Comment: can u post you imports as well?

Comment: My import:
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

Comment: Have you asked this before ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292126/change-android-action-bar-menu-items-icon-on-click

Comment: Yes I did. On my old question, I manage to change the current "on clicked" item. But now I want to change the other item on the same click as well.

Comment: what do you mean by change the other item? Be specific.

Comment: I have 2 menu items, when I click the "a" item for example, I want the "a" items's icon change and "b" items's icon change as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35689/discussion-between-mohit-and-adyana-permatasari)

Answer (score 4):

Every time you want to make changes to your items in the Action bar you have to call the function 
invalidateOptionsMenu(). Then you override the method public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu), there you get your menu items and you can set icons, create new actions or remove them. Hope it helps.